# Coloring break commands

Tags: html, css

I was creating a page which uses css to have a background color of #F5FFF6...
Here's my code

```
#page_content {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
background-color: #F5FFF6;
}
```

It worked and my page was a beautiful light-green. But I've discovered that every time I add a *break command* (the "br/") that one line becomes completely white. It really looks ugly because my site is like a light green with white stripes in it..

So I  decided to try and color the break command but to no avail. Can you please help me how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the background of the entire page to that color, then:

```
body{
  background-color: #F5FFF6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. In a completely unrelated topic, do you know how to make a table fluid? I mean like when you zoom in your browser the table won't auto-inlarge itself? because when I try it to other computers with different resolutions, the table expands itself ruining the site's contents..

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `position="fixed"`? If that doesn't work, make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/fpC8L/
As you can see, if you try to zoom in the site, the table will expand and will get out of the fieldset which is the main problem

Comment: Do you need the `position` to be `relative`? I have a feeling that that's your issue.

Comment: Honestly I really don't know how that relative works. I just included it in my code because someone recommended it to me. However, i tried removing that position:relative; code but still the result is the same..

Comment: I really want to run in any computer with different resolution than mines because if I run it to other computers which have lower reso. than my computer, the table grows -- ruining the design

Comment: I'm not exactly getting what you're describing; can you show me a screenshot?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/r3nr147hr/ here it is..
the table expand itself when zooming in and ruined the design

Comment: You had `width: 100%` instead of `width = 100%`; fixing that makes the border stretch across the whole table, which may fix the problem. If not, then I don't know what to tell you...there's probably some hacky way of doing it with CSS, in which case I would ask another question about that specifically, but otherwise, that's the default behavior; I see what you're seeing but that doesn't seem to be a problem for me on other resolutions. The only way I see that is if I zoom in an insane amount.

Comment: Thanks man! I finally found the problem -- I was using (px) instead of (%) in my width, height, and stuffs that's why when I zoom in it automatically expands itself! Thank you so much for your help today. Peace and God bless to you!